# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4' with bs4 installed and worked in cmd

Tags: python, web-scraping

I have already installed bs4 and it works well in the cmd like this

```
C:\Users\Ronium>python
Python 3.6.5 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Mar 29 2018, 13:32:41) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup('<p>Hello</p>','html.parser')
>>> soup.find('p').text
'Hello'
```

but when i import it in the py. file it gives me an error

```
O:\Unify\WebScraper>Graphics.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "O:\Unify\WebScraper\Graphics.py", line 2, in <module>
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4'
```

ADDITION:
python is actually working in the O:\ as well

```
O:\Unify\WebScraper>python
Python 3.6.5 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Mar 29 2018, 13:32:41) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
>>> soup = soup('<p>Hello</p>', 'html.parser')
>>> soup.find('p').text
'Hello'
>>>
```

Comment: Presumably you're running a different version of Python between the two cases.

Comment: Sounds fair. I found i have also installed python 3.7 in my pc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think i have solved this prob cuz i found i also have python 3.7 installed in my pc, when i try to run the py. file it actually executed the 3.7 version where bs4 is not installed.

Thanks Guys

Answer (score 0):

You're in a different drive, "O:\" when you're running the python script.

Make sure you have python installed in the O:\ drive or run your python file from the C:\ drive and it should work!

Comment: did you try `python "your_script.py"` yet?

Comment: i think i have solve this prob cuz i found i also have python 3.7 installed in my pc, when i try to run the py. file it actually executed the 3.7 version where bs4 is not installed.

Comment: Yeah python versioning is important.